# Rest api version v45.0 not working

Tags: rest-api, servicecloud

Rest apis below version v45.0 working fine. But new version v45.0 is not working. Getting error as

[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]

Comment: are you on Spring 19? if not it wont work

Comment: whats the logo of the org when loading ?

Comment: Please clarify *"not working"*. Do you get an error? If so please **[edit]** your post to include the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v45 is Spring 19. If your org is not on Spring 19 you won't be able to access v45 API.

A quick way to see the which version your org is to just log in and see the loading animation.

If this is the animation then you will be able to use v45.

[image]

You have to wait till next weekend as Spring 19 will reach all orgs then.
Src: https://status.salesforce.com/instances/AP0/maintenances